# Meteor: Should I use showdown or markdown?

Tags: meteor

When you take a look at the [showdown package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/showdown), you can see the following lines in the [package.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/showdown/package.js) file:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Moved to the 'markdown' package",
  version: '1.0.2-pre.2'
});
```

The markdown package [is available here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/markdown) but we can't read anything about it [in the official documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#showdown).

So I'm just wondering, should I use `meteor add showdown` or `meteor add markdown`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the meteor changelog for v.NEXT (METEOR@0.9.4) :

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

> Rename the showdown package to markdown.

For the moment, continue using `showdown` unless you are running the 0.9.4 preview, which has not yet reached release candidacy, either case be prepared to move on to `markdown` in a near future.

By the way, the legacy `showdown` package will simply `api.imply` markdown for backward compatibility as you can read from the source.